# system_thread_exception not handled in windows

Tags: operating-system, system

I always hear about the `system_thread_exception` not being handled in Windows OS -
what is the essence of this problem, and how can we avoid it? Also, why is this problem Windows-specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559239(v=vs.85).aspx) is the bug check 0x7e:

> The `SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` bug check has a value of 0x0000007E. This bug check indicates that a system thread generated an exception that the error handler did not catch.
>
> ...
>
> **Cause**
>
> The SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED bug check is a very common bug check. To interpret it, you must identify which exception was generated.
>
> Common exception codes include the following:
>
> - 0x80000002: STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT indicates an unaligned data reference was encountered.
> - 0x80000003: STATUS_BREAKPOINT indicates a breakpoint or ASSERT was encountered when no kernel debugger was attached to the system.
> - 0xC0000005: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION indicates a memory access violation occurred.

To avoid this, read about [Handling Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546823(v=vs.85).aspx) for how driver developers should write code that properly handles exceptions. Is it Windows specific since we're talking about windows drivers development and kernel BSOD codes.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error and tried various drivers for the WiFi card on my Laptop. Nothing worked and I **kept getting the blue screen until I bought a new WiFi module card** from Intel (Atheros Qualcom was originally installed).
And after that no more blue screens